# MySql - Tricky "Group by" and count

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count number of championships and competitions pr season.
Some background:
 - each championships can have one or more competitions
 - Our season is from 1 Oct to 30 Sept

Championship table:

ChampID (small int), Name, Startdate (date), +++

Competitions table:

CompID (small int), ChampID (small int), +++

I know I have too use a left join, i.e. "left  join competition on competition.champid = championship.champid".
But I'm struggeling to find:

- an expression to group by our season
- count the number of championships and competitions pr season

This is the best I've come up with, but the counts of championships and competitions pr season

```
select DATE_FORMAT(startdate, "%Y") as ChampYear 
      , count(championship.champid)
      , count(competition.compid) 
   from championship
   left  
   join competition 
     on competition.champid = championship.champid
  GROUP 
     BY floor(period_diff( DATE_FORMAT(startdate, "%Y%m"), "201910") / 12);
```

Can any of you experts show me a way forward?

Comment: what is the data type for the column startdate ???

Comment: Startdate data type is "date"

Comment: PS: My sample count is wrong, they will ion my sample be the same, whereas there is always more competitions than Championships.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try checking for month>9  for assigne the season/champYear

and you should aslo use count distinct for avoid the conut of duplicated  value  count()

```
    select case when month(startdate)>9 
                then year(startdate) else year(startdate)-1 end ChampYear 
        , count(distinct championship.champid)
        , count(distinct competition.compid) 
    from championship
    left  join competition on competition.champid = championship.champid
    GROUP BY ChampYear;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count the championships/competitions for your season (startdate = 10/2019), a simple `WHERE` should be enough.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(startdate, "%Y") as ChampYear, count(championship.champid), count(competition.compid) 
FROM championship
LEFT JOIN competition on competition.champid = championship.champid
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(startdate, "%Y%m") = "201910"
```

Comment: Our database has data going back to 1999 and I would like to do a count for the full history.

Comment: In that case you have to replace the `WHERE` with `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(startdate, "%Y%m")`

Comment: Still the counts will be wrong, the number of Competitions will almost always be higher than number of Championships.